# Special Character Issue : MQ message PUT error : java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException

Tags: java, character-encoding, jms, ibm-mq

I have a setup where there is a JMS Producer and JMS receiver. The sender application sends a message like :

```
source text ⟨е, ё, и, ю, я⟩  abcdefg
```

JMS receiver after receiving the message, puts it to a IBM MQ queue using pure IBM MQ API classes.

While putting this message to MQ I am getting the below exception:

```
INFO  | 2020-09-17 09:45:19 | [main] mimq.MQReceiver (MQReceiver.java:211) - IO Exception Occurred: Input length = 1
java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
        at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:282)
        at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:816)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage.stringToBytes(JmqiCodepage.java:923)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.writeString(MQMessage.java:2848)
        at com.ibm.mimq.MQReceiver.sendToAnotherQueue(MQReceiver.java:192)
        at com.ibm.mimq.MQReceiver.main(MQReceiver.java:113)
```

Below is my **MQ PUT** code :

```
public static void sendToLocalQueue(String msg) {
    
    int port = 1414;
    String host = "some-host";
    String channel = "some-channel";
    String manager = "some-QM";
    String user = "user"; 
    String passwd = "passwd";
    String qname = "TEST";
    String qmname = "some-QM";
    
    MQQueueManager qMgr;
    MQQueue inputQ;
    
    try {       
        
        Hashtable<String, String> h = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        h.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
        MQEnvironment.properties = h;
        MQEnvironment.hostname  = host;
        MQEnvironment.port      = port;
        MQEnvironment.channel   = channel;
        
        MQEnvironment.userID    = user;
        MQEnvironment.password  = passwd;
        MQEnvironment.disableTracing();
        MQException.log = null;
        qMgr = new MQQueueManager(manager);
        
        MQMessage m = new MQMessage();      
        m.applicationOriginData = "AMPS";
        m.messageType   = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
        m.format        = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
        m.encoding      = MQC.MQENC_NATIVE;
        m.priority      = 4;
        m.persistence   = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;
        m.characterSet  = MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR;
        //m.characterSet = 1208;
        m.expiry        =  MQC.MQEI_UNLIMITED;
        m.writeString(msg);
        
        MQPutMessageOptions putOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
        putOptions.options = MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT | MQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING; 
        
        logger.info("Putting message to LAN MQ (TEST queue)....");          
        qMgr.put(qname, qmname, m, putOptions);
        qMgr.commit();
        
        
    } catch(MQException me) {
        logger.info("Error Code       : "  +me.getErrorCode());
        logger.info("LocalizedMessage : "  +me.getLocalizedMessage());
        logger.info("Message          : "  +me.getMessage());
        logger.info("Reason           : "  +me.getReason());
        me.printStackTrace();
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        logger.info("IO Exception Occurred       : "  +e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

It is unable to put the message to the queue due to Unmappable character. The encoding is set to UTF-8 at Queue Manager level.

However when I replace the below line :     `m.characterSet     = MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR;`

With the line :     `m.characterSet = 1208;`  The issue is no more there.

My question is why this conversion is not getting done at MQ level. What are settings I need to check to ensure the correct conversion. I have tried the below techniques, but not working :

```
Setting java parameter as : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

My **environment** :

```
Server : Linux
MQ : 9.0  or 7.5
Java : 1.8
```

One more thing to mention, the same setup was working with 7.5 but not working with MQ 9.0 after migration. I know with my above one line code change I can pass the message. But I want to understand in MQ level, if I am missing out some configurations. Any advise would be much appreciated.

Thank You.

**UPDATE**

The Client Machine from where I am sending the Message over to MQ has CCSID : `MQMD.CodedCharSetId = 1208`

The MQ server where I am connecting and sending the message has this :

```
getDefaultProperty(Object) returns [819(0x333)] Integer
setCCSID(int) setter [819(0x333)]
```

So when I am setting 1208 explicitely in my code it is working. When not the conversion is failing.

**UPDATE-2**

The value `MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR is Zero` as I saw in the jar. Hence the code is designed like this, if the value is Zero, it will fetch the default value from the Jar which is set to **819**. I learnt this when I turned on the MQ tracing. And the code is like this :

```
getDefaultProperty(Object) returns [819(0x333)] Integer
setCCSID(int) setter [819(0x333)]
```

This code is present inside the jar. So we need to explicitly set the charset value on the message. In my case it is 1208.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this worked at MQ v7.5 and not at MQ v9.0 is because prior to IBM MQ v8.0 the IBM MQ classes for Java encoded data using `java.nio.charset.Charset.encode(CharBuffer)` which results in a default replacement of malformed or untranslatable data.  Since the default `characterSet` is 819 (ASCII), this would result in any character you send that can not be converted to ASCII to be transparently replaced with the default replacement character, in most cases this means the data was replaced with the `?` character.

After v8.0 the default behavior changed to report this situation as an error and no longer replace malformed or untranslatable data by default.

---

Your solution to set the character set to UTF-8 is the best solution as this results in the exact data you intended to send being sent.

Another option is to tell MQ to use the prior behavior.

---

The description of the new behavior as well as how to configure IBM MQ classes for Java to use the prior behavior is described in the IBM MQ 9.0 Knowledge Center page [Developing applications>Developing JMS and Java applications>Using IBM MQ classes for Java>Character string conversions in IBM MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120590_.htm):

> From IBM® MQ Version 8.0, some of the default behavior regarding
> character string conversion in the IBM MQ classes for Java™ has
> changed.
>
> Before IBM MQ Version 8.0, string conversions in IBM MQ classes for
> Java was done by calling the
> java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(ByteBuffer) and
> Charset.encode(CharBuffer) methods.
>
> Using either of these methods results in a default replacement (
> REPLACE) of malformed or untranslatable data.
>
> This behavior can obscure errors in applications, and lead to
> unexpected characters, for example ?, in translated data. From IBM MQ
> Version 8.0, to detect such issues earlier and more effectively, the
> IBM MQ classes for Java use CharsetEncoders and CharsetDecoders
> directly and configure the handling of malformed and untranslatable
> data explicitly.
>
> From IBM MQ Version 8.0, the default behavior is to REPORT such issues
> by throwing a suitable MQException.
>
> ...
>
> **Setting system defaults**
> --
>
> From IBM MQ Version 8.0, the following two Java system properties are
> available to configure default behavior regarding character string
> conversion.
>
> **com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterAction**     Specifies the action to be taken for untranslatable data on encoding and decoding.
> The value can be REPORT, REPLACE, or IGNORE.
>
> **com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterReplacement**     Sets or gets the replacement bytes to apply when a character cannot be mapped
> in an encoding operation The default Java replacement string is used
> in decoding operations.
>
> To avoid confusion between Java character and native byte
> representations, you should specify
> com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterReplacement as a decimal number
> representing the replacement byte in the native character set.
>
> For example, the decimal value of ?, as a native byte, is 63 if the
> native character set is ASCII-based, such as ISO-8859-1, while it is
> 111 if the native character set is EBCDIC.

---

If you wanted to mimic the prior behavior you would set the following system properties:

```
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterAction=REPLACE
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterReplacement=63
```

You can also set it Programmatically with something like this:

```
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterAction", "REPLACE");
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterReplacement", "63");
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I came to know about this later on. Up voting. Thanks @JoshMc

Answer (score 3):

When connected locally to the queue manager (i.e. using `TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS`) then the code:-

```
m.characterSet     = MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR;
```

means "take the CCSID set in the queue manager property CCSID". You can see this property using the following MQSC command:-

```
DISPLAY QMGR CCSID
```

When connected as a client (as your code shows you are), then the code:-

```
m.characterSet     = MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR;
```

means "find the CCSID from the client machine locale".

[IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097460_.htm) states:-

> For client applications, `MQCCSI_Q_MGR` is filled in, based on the locale of the client rather than the one on the queue manager.

It would seem that your client machine locale is not set to UTF-8 if changing the line of code to explicitly set the message CCSID to 1208 fixes the problem.

You can see what is set by the client, by browsing the message on the queue (without converting it) and looking what is in the `MQMD.CodedCharSetId` field.

Comment: : I have updated my question. Please see once again.

Comment: Hi @Som - I see that you have updated your question, but it is not clear what else you need to know. Have you checked the locale of your client machine?

Comment: Also, one other thing @Som - did you discover what was being filled into the MQMD.CodedCharSetId of the message when you didn't over-ride it to 1208? Did you try browsing the message (without conversion) when it is on the queue?

Comment: What I saw is when I try to put the message it is fetching the default CCSID as `819` from MQ jar  when I set `MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR`. This field has been deprecated now and has a value = 0. So it is fetching the default value 819 and which fails to encode the message. The main issue is with this default value. We need to set 1208 at client end explicitly.  I came to this conclusion after doing a trace on. But Your answer gave me a very fantastic go through. I will accept your answer though. Much Thanks ! appreciated.

Comment: for your last comment I saw the value to be 1208. `Encoding : 273  CodedCharSetId : 1208`. I browsed the message and I saw this. But my client code is setting `MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR`, hence it is getting changed. And hence the error.

Comment: Morag, he is getting the error from IBM MQ classes for Java when calling `qMgr.put(qname, qmname, m, putOptions);`, I don't think the message would ever make it to the queue to look at.

Comment: @JoshMc - it doesn't have to be this message - a plain invariant ASCII string message wouldn't fail, and then you can see what the CodedCharSetId being set is. Sounds like he has found the code in the jars and it is always 819 anyway, so this step not needed. Overall answer - he has to set 1208 in his code.