# webshpere 9 message driven bean . 'JMSADM4125 q unmappable replacement' error

Tags: websphere, ejb, ibm-mq

I have ejb message driven bean on was 8 java 6. every think work well.

The message driver bean listened on mq queue .
the queue on MainFrame

I migrated from WAS 8 to WAS 9 (java 8) .

Some messages include characters that cannot converted and cause exception :

```
JMSCMQ1049: The character set '424(IBM424) Unmappable Action: REPORT
```

I found an article that talks about the problem

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=java-character-string-conversions-in-mq-classes

> **Character string conversions in IBM MQ classes for Java**
>
> The IBM® MQ classes for Java use CharsetEncoders and CharsetDecoders
> directly for character string conversion.  The default behavior for
> character string conversion can be configured with two system
> properties. The handling of messages that contain unmappable
> characters can be configured through com.ibm.mq.MQMD.
>
> Before IBM MQ 8.0, string conversions in IBM MQ classes for Java was done by calling the java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(ByteBuffer)
> and Charset.encode(CharBuffer) methods.
>
> Using either of these methods results in a default replacement ( REPLACE) of malformed or untranslatable data. This behavior can
> obscure errors in applications, and lead to unexpected characters, for
> example ?, in translated data.
>
> From IBM MQ 8.0, to detect such issues earlier and more effectively, the IBM MQ classes for Java use CharsetEncoders and
> CharsetDecoders directly and configure the handling of malformed and
> untranslatable data explicitly. The default behavior is to REPORT such
> issues by throwing a suitable MQException.

What I do not know, is how to implement the solution that the article
offers within the JMS settings of the queue in webSphere admin console or in java implementation

Anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The link provided has the information below:

> com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterAction Specifies the action to
> be taken for untranslatable data on encoding and decoding. The value
> can be REPORT, REPLACE, or IGNORE.
> com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterReplacement Sets or gets the
> replacement bytes to apply when a character cannot be mapped in an
> encoding operation The default Java replacement string is used in
> decoding operations.

---

If you wanted to mimic the prior behavior you would set the following system properties as generic JVM arguments the following link discusses how to set the arguments: [Setting generic JVM arguments in WebSphere Application Server](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/setting-generic-jvm-arguments-websphere-application-server)

```
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterAction=REPLACE
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.UnmappableCharacterReplacement=63
```

---

For a more detailed answer that is not specific to WAS see this:
[Special Character Issue : MQ message PUT error : java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935780/special-character-issue-mq-message-put-error-java-nio-charset-unmappablechar/63961446#63961446)